# hooks array is not pushing the last item react native

Tags: react-native

i have this code whish scan barcodes and push them to my array the problem is that the affectation is not working correctly for example when i push "a" the array is still epmty and then when i push b the array take the previus value pushed array["a"] and when i push c it's like array["a","b'].
this is the declaration of the array :

```
 const [array, setarray] = useState([]);
```

and here is muy function :

```
     alert(
       `barcode of type ${type} and value ${data} scanned successfully`
     );
     await setarray([...array, data]);
     console.log("my array :  ", array);
```

Comment: afaik, `setarray` is not a promise function. You can use useEffect hook for that

Comment: how can i push a value to the array with useEffect

Comment: just take away async/await, you don't need them to pass in values to useState.

Comment: i tryed that but it's not working correctly even without await i even tryed this :       setarray(arr => ([...arr, data]));
but still the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write something to `state variable`, you are doing it right.

```
 const [array, setarray] = useState([]);
```

However, the `setarray` is a method to change the `state variable` [memory cell](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#under-the-hood) (something like pointer).

You can't access the new "pointed" value with

```
console.log("my array :  ", array);
```

The suggested way is to `useEffect` to take [effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

```
useEffect(()=>{
// every render
  console.log("my array :  ", array);
})
```

You might want to take effect only when the array is changed, so we would add a dependency there.

```
useEffect(()=>{
// once the array changed
  console.log("my array :  ", array);
}, [array])
```